# How to render conditional html

Tags: vue.js

I have to render some html code based on conditions like:

```
if (status == 'pending') {
  // render <span class='pending'>pending</span>
} else {
  // render <span class='complete'>complete</span>
}
```

I would like a better way to to this.
Is ok to use computed properties to render html ?

Comment: You shouldn't be rendering plain HTML anyway, just put it in the template and use things like `v-if` to control the visibility.

Comment: even if I have 6 ifs ?

Answer (score 0):

You may looking for v-if

<span v-if=“status==‘pending’” >....

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `v-if` directive:

```
<span class='pending' v-if="status === 'pending'">
    pending
</span>
<span class='complete' v-else>
    complete
</span>
```

See more details: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bunch of different statuses, then you can have something like this in the template:

```vue
<span v-if="status" :class="status">{{ status }}</span>
```

The span will be displayed when `status` is truthy and the class and inner text will be set to the status value.